# How to specify ApplicationName in NpgSql connection string

Tags: postgresql, c#-4.0, ado.net, npgsql

Is it possible to to specify ApplicationName in NpgSql connection string? The following resource usually helps, but it says nothing in this case: [Npgsql connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/)

Answer (score 13):

`ApplicationName` works for me - `"Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=***;Password=***;Database=***;ApplicationName=test"`.

Answer (score 3):

In case there are people who searched for answer to this question, here is the solution:
application_name=MyApp will not work for npgsql version 2.2.4.3 (Latest Released 2015-02-05)
Change application_name to ApplicationName=MyApp