# Web.Config: Connection String with Application name

Tags: postgresql, connection-string, npgsql

I am really struggling to get this to work. I have a connection string and I want to add the application name with an NpgSql provider. According [to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046578/how-to-specify-applicationname-in-npgsql-connection-string) I should use `ApplicationName`, and according to the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-connect.html) I should use `application_name`. The problem I an having is that neither of those work for me.

Connection String:

```
<add name="Site" connectionString="Server=******;Port=******;Database==******;User Id==******;Password==******;SearchPath==******;ApplicationName=test" providerName="NpgSql"/>
```

Error:

```
key=value argument incorrect in ConnectionString
Parameter name: applicationname
```

Connection String:

```
<add name="Site" connectionString="Server=******;Port=******;Database==******;User Id==******;Password==******;SearchPath==******;application_name=test" providerName="NpgSql"/>
```

Error:

```
key=value argument incorrect in ConnectionString
Parameter name: application_name
```

Answer (score 3):

In case there are people who searched for answer to this question, here is the solution:
application_name=MyApp will not work for npgsql version 2.2.4.3 (Latest Released 2015-02-05)
Change application_name to ApplicationName=MyAp
Answered also provided to the link posted by the questioner above.